# Is it possible to rebind the std::bind to another function with additional arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

Consider you have some function that you wrapped using `std::bind` with some bounded arguments:

```cpp
void func1(std::string& arg1, std::unique_ptr<int>& arg2)
{
    ...
}
...

auto f1 = std::bind(func1, std::string{"message"}, std::make_unique<int>(123));
```

Now, imagine for whatever reason you want to rebind this object to another function having some additional argument(s), for example:

```cpp
void func2(std::exception& ex, std::string& arg1, std::unique_ptr<int>& arg2)
{
    ...
}
...

try {
    f1();
} catch (std::exception& ex) {
    auto f2 = some_magical_rebind(func2, std::move(ex), args_of(f1));
}
```

Is it possible to do that ? As `std::bind` uses `std::tuple` internally to pack the arguments it feels that should be possible.

Comment: not according to the standard, the type of the result of `std::bind` is not specified

Comment: "*As std::bind uses std::tuple internally to pack the arguments*" That is an implementation detail which is in no way required by the standard.

Comment: What is the problem you have - to rebind another function to `f1` or to extract arguments of `func1()`?

Comment: Possible if and only if you design own function and arguments holder object, using std::tuple for example.

Comment: `decltype` is usally helpful

Comment: @Slava Basically to dispatch the args of func1 to another function (slightly different one) if the call fails

Comment: @S.M. Do you know an example of such a design ?

Comment: I'm confused by the premise of this question. The context of the try-catch block is aware of `f1`'s signature (as evident by `f2`)? Then why are the arguments bound at all?

Comment: Just googled https://gist.github.com/Redchards/c5be14c2998f1ca1d757

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `std::bind` has very limited functionality (stores bound parameters, copy/moveable based on the stored parameters, callable, and the ability to detect if it the return of `std::bind`), and extracting the bound parameters is not part of its interface. So there is no way to do what you want with `std::bind`. You would need to build your own form of `std::bind` which provides the interface you're interested in.

Comment: I think this particular problem can be solved much easier than implementing your own variant of `std::bind` :)

Comment: Almost any problem can be made easier by not using std bind.

Comment: Here it is not even using `std::bind` but writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Just store parameters in variables and use more generic `std::function` rather than auto of `std::bind` result:

```
auto msg = std::string( "message" );
auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>( 123 );
std::function<void()> f = std::bind( func1, std::ref( msg ), std::ref( ptr ) );


try {
    f();
}
catch( std::exception& ex) {
    f = std::bind( func2, ex, std::ref( msg ), std::ref( ptr ) );
}
```

or you can pack them into one structure or `std::tuple` if you prefer.

Comment: That does not extract the arguments from `f`, but instead relies on the arguments still being in scope.